# angularjs foreach loop issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I'm new to AngularJS and I'd like to build an `object` with data from a `json` file.

This is my `json` file:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "user1", "select": false },
  {"id": 2, "name": "user2", "select": false },
  {"id": 3, "name": "user3", "select": false },
  {"id": 4, "name": "user4", "select": false },
  {"id": 5, "name": "user5", "select": false }
]
```

And now I want to use `foreach` loop to check which user has got **select == true** and push this username to new `array`. So here is my first Try:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('apiOmat', [])


  .controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('users.json').then(function(usersResponse) {
      $scope.users = usersResponse.data;
    });


$scope.submit = function(message,title){

var tempArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.users.name, function(value,key){
 tempArr.push(value);
});

console.log(tempArr);

    $scope.messagebody = '{ "title" = "' + title + '", "message" = "' + message  + '"}'; 
}

 });
```

I also tried this:

```
  $scope.submit = function(message,title){

    var tempArr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value,key){
     tempArr.push( { key :  value } );
    });

    console.log(tempArr);
```

The Console logs the 5 object, but without any value. Just 
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object 
...

I know that the query for true or false is missing. But I want to fix this step before adding a query.

Comment: Try this `angular.forEach($scope.users,function(user){tempArr.push( user)})`.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks! It worked almost. I just used tempArr.push( username) to get the names of my user.

Comment: this is not angular for each loop issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this:

> And now I want to use a foreach-loop to check which user has got
>   select == true and push this username to my new array

```
$scope.submit = function(message,title){
   var tempArr = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.users, function(item){
     if( item.select == true){
       tempArr.push(item);
     }
   });
```

Another **simple & better** solution is to use `filter` instead.

```
$scope.submit = function(message,title){
    var tempArr = ($scope.users).filter(function(d){
         return (d.select == true);
    });
 });

console.log(tempArr)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Comment: try second one it is more better :)

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
$scope.submit = function(message,title){

var tempArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.users, function(i,j){

if(i.select == true)
{
 tempArr.push( i.name );
  }
});

console.log(tempArr);
```

Comment: This solution is not checking for select == true, I guess that is the main purpose you are iterating on the array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $scope.submit = function(message,title){
   var tempArr = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user){
   tempArr.push( {"name":user.name} );
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var tempArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user){
    user.select && tempArr.push(user.name);
});

console.dir(tempArr);
```

Comment: Maybe it is  because all of your users have "select" = false?? It works fine.http://jsfiddle.net/qp9qapgm/

Comment: I copied not everything. My fault, sorry :D

Comment: Could you explain me something? I don't get that "user.select && tempArr.push(user.name);"

Is that a short form for "if( item.select == true){
       tempArr.push(item);"?

Comment: @Paili Yes. Javascript uses lazy evaluation of logic expressions. In my case, it firstly checks that user.select is true (or another value that converts to true, see js doc). If it is, then js goes to second expression and evaluates it. Otherwise second expression is skipped, because all result will anyway equal to true and it is unnecessary to resolve all other stuff after 'false'.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) @Boris Parnikel

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
$scope.submit = function(message, title){
   var tempArr = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user){
    if( user.select == true) //filter select:true only
      tempArr.push( {"name_as_key":user.name} ); //name_as_key can be replaced if intended to
   });
```